# Setting opaque to custom color in android (setAlpha)

Tags: java, android

How can I get my color and set opaque to it?

```
int myColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.html#setAlphaComponent(int,%20int)) to create a new color value with the same RGB but different alpha. The alpha value needs be from 0 - 255 so it would look something like this:

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary);
int color50percent = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(color, 128);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is example color black alpha 65

```
 <color name="ColorPrimary">#A6000000</color>
```

if you want change opacity just change 2 number in front
hope it help

Answer (score 0):

setAlpha is applied on views. Get your view and then use `.setColor(...)` and `.setAlpha(...)` .